# как из dict превратить обратно в str?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
text = input('some text >> ')

text = text.split('')

print(type(text)) #dict
```

как из dict обратно в str вернуть?

Comment: метод `split` возвращает список, а не словарь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
text = input('some text >> ')
text = text.split('')
print(type(text)) #list
    
text = ' '.join(text)
    
print(type(text)) #str
```

При помощи `.join()` мы объединили все объекты списка в одну строку через пробел.